# Avraham, Av Hamon, Av ha'am

Tags: sources-mekorot, avot-patriarch-fathers

Avraham seems to mean a father of a multitude or exalted father. 
But is there any scripture that calls him Av Ha'am? A father of nations or our nation?

I read an article which wrote that Avraham was a Av Ha'am, but I wonder if this terminology of Av Ha'am was mentioned anywhere in the Talmud or other scriptures? Because the Torah calls him a father of a multitude of nations (goyim) and not amim or just am.

Comment: perhaps av aram

Answer (score -1):

The answer as far as I can tell, is that no -- Avraham is not called 'Av HaAm' in any classical Jewish sources.

Source: This term is not found in the rather comprehensive Bar Ilan Responsa database in reference to him.

Comment: Commentless downvotes?

Comment: @J.Levi If you like an answer, consider marking it correct :)

Answer (score -2):

does this help?

"No longer shall you be called 'Abram.' Your name shall be 'Abraham,' for I have made you the father of many nations."  (Gen. 17:5)

from [here](http://ravkooktorah.org/LECH_LECHA_68.htm)

or perhaps "Look unto Abraham your father, and unto Sarah that bore you: for I called him alone, and blessed him, and increased him" Isaiah 51:2

Comment: Those are well known scriptures form the Tenach, i read an aricle which wrote that Avraham was a Av Ha'am, but i wondered if this terminology of Av Ha'am was mentioned anywere in the Talmud or other scriptures ? Because the Torah calls him a father of a multitude of nations (goyim) and not amim or just am.

Comment: @J.Levi those are the closest in the tanach i think